# Predict wind data using neural network in python

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network

I want to predict wind data using past wind data.So this this is my changed code.In my code prediction output is numeric values.So I can' understand how to change accuracy function in this code.

This is my code url.

http://myit13092702.blogspot.com/2016/07/prediction-using-neural-network-in.html

Comment: First of all, the accuracy function doesn't determine what your model learns, it just evaluates how well your model performs on the test data. You should explain a little deeper what you want to do. It is a regression or a classification task? Where did you get the code from? What have you changed?

Comment: I want to predict wind data using historical data.(I have 10 years past wind data).Using these data I want to predict wind data for future.So I use classification algorithm. In classification algorithm so many algorithms. Among these I use Neural network algorithm.I find a code using neural network in python.This code url is http://myit13092702.blogspot.com/2016/07/predict-data-using-neural-network.html

Comment: Below I mention my changed code.Sample code prediction output is string value.So it is ok. But In my code prediction output is numeric values.So I can't understand how to change accuracy function in this code.Please help me. Thanks a lot. 

This is my code url.

http://myit13092702.blogspot.com/2016/07/prediction-using-neural-network-in.html

Comment: I change code training data-set,test data-set,Input output hidden layers and accuracy function.Like this..                                                              if (float(t_values[max_index]) < 0.85) & (float(t_values[max_index]) > 0.15):
        num_correct += 1;
      else:
        num_wrong += 1;

Comment: In sample code has like this...                                                                      if t_values[max_index] == 1.0:
        num_correct += 1;                                                                              in accuracy function.I can't understand how to change my code to right one.Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I mention above in my code I change accuracy function,but I don't know how to change t_values condition correctly.